How to give dark tint to Google Maps in Android
I am using Google Maps in my Android app, I want to give maps a little tint, it is too bright. I tried using another box but the markers also get tinted too, I want only the map to have a slightly dark color and the markers to be bright.
Code-
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
) {
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
            GoogleMapOptions().mapId(MapDefaults.mapId)
        },
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = style.mapProperties,
        uiSettings = style.mapUiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = {
            onMapLoaded()
        }
    ) {
       //Markers
    }

}
Like this in FlightRadar24 map-
only the map has dark tint, markers are bright.

If I use Night mode then whole map gets dark-

Same for Dark mode -

But in FlightRadar24 the background map is a normal type with a light black cover.
How can I get that?

To darken the Google Maps in your Android app without affecting the markers, you can apply a color overlay to the map directly through Google Maps' styling API, rather than using a box overlay that tints everything.
Step 1: Create a Map Style JSON
Create a JSON file in your res/raw directory (e.g., map_style.json) that defines a darker map style. Here’s a basic example of a darker style:
Step 2: Apply the Style in Code
In your GoogleMap call, load and apply this style using the MapProperties:
val context = LocalContext.current

val mapProperties = remember {
    MapProperties(
        mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context, R.raw.map_style)
    )
}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
) {
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
            GoogleMapOptions().mapId(MapDefaults.mapId)
        },
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = mapProperties,
        uiSettings = style.mapUiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = {
            onMapLoaded()
        }
    ) {
       // Markers remain unaffected by the map style
    }
}


This approach will darken only the map itself while keeping the markers bright, as they won’t be affected by the map style.

Thanks for replying Shreyash, Could you please also tell me how to create Map Style JSON, which gives a dark tint to the map? I tried, but it gave too much dark color

As Shreyas P said you can do it simply using JSON, here is a full step by step approach to style the Google Map.
Step 1. Create a JSON Style File

Create a new file named map_style.json.
Add the following content to it for a dark theme:

[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"  // Dark color for geometry
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"  // Hide icons
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"  // Light grey color for text
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"  // Dark background for text labels
      }
    ]
  }
]

If you want full description that how the JSON is made click here.
Step 2. Load the JSON in Your Code

Place the JSON file into res/raw directory.
Use MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle() to load the JSON style using Shreyas P's method.

val context = LocalContext.current

val mapProperties = remember {
    MapProperties(
        mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context, R.raw.map_style)
    )
}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
) {
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
            GoogleMapOptions().mapId(MapDefaults.mapId)
        },
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = mapProperties,
        uiSettings = style.mapUiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = {
            onMapLoaded()
        }
    ) {
       // Markers remain unaffected by the map style
    }
}


I hope it's helpful
